# Santum 419 CORS issue

Tags: php, vuejs3, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

I've found a lot of question about this issue but none of those answers work for me.
I'm trying to authenticate a user from my vuejs SPA to laravel 10.9 sanctum API.

It seems like the axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie') in the login function is ok but there is noting
in application->cookies in the browser.

Then when I hit /login end point, I get this error:

`http://localhost:8000/auth/login 419 (unknown status).`.

with this in browser network tab:
`. "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",` .

Here are my files:

## **FRONT END

## **

axios config (api.js):

```
    import axios from "axios";

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
    });

    export default api;
```

Auth-api.js:

```
    import api from './api';
    export const csrfCookie = () => api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

    export const login = (credentials) => api.post('/auth/login', credentials);

    export const logout = () => api.post('/auth/logout');

    export const register = (user) => api.post('/auth/register', user);

    export const getUser = () => api.get('/api/user');
```

auth.js store file:

```
     import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
     import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
     import { csrfCookie, login, register, logout, getUser } from '../http/auth-api';

     export const useAuthStore = defineStore("authStore", () => {

       const user = ref(null);
       const isLoggedIn = computed(() => !!user.value);

       const fetchUser = async () => {
          const {data} = await getUser();
          user.value = data;
       }

      const handleLongin = async (credentials) => {
        await csrfCookie();
        await login(credentials);
        await fetchUser();
      }

      const handleRegister = async (user) => {

        await register(user);
        await handleLongin({email: user.email, password: user.password});
      }

      const handleLogout = async () => {
        await logout();
        user.value = null;
      }


      return {
        handleLogout,
        handleLongin,
        handleRegister,
        isLoggedIn,
        user,
        fetchUser
      }


    });
```

LoginPage.vue:

```
    <template>
      <section class="auth-wrapper">
        <form class="auth-form" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
          <h1>
           <span>ToeDoe</span>
           <strong>List</strong>
          </h1>
          <h2 class="h3 mb-4 fw-normal">Please sign in</h2>
          <div class="form-floating mb-2">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" v-model="form.email" placeholder="name@example.com" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
           <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="form.password"   placeholder="Password" />
           <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
          <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </template>
<script setup>
    import { reactive } from 'vue';
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
    import {useAuthStore} from '../stores/auth';


    const router = useRouter();
    const store = useAuthStore();
    const {handleLongin} = store;

const form = reactive({
  email: null,
  password: null
});

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  await handleLongin(form);
  router.push({name: 'tasks'});
}

</script>

<style scoped>
.auth-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 60vh;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.auth-form {
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

## **BACK END

## **

.env:

```
APP_NAME=todoApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:PQAHb3RaPGe4Pdk+F4qdmZKflJCUmwD8B5jRDPUE9b4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

FRONTEND_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5173
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:5173

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=...
DB_USERNAME=...
DB_PASSWORD=...

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

cors.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'auth/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1:5173')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

sanctum.php:

```
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
      'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
      'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

kernetl.php:

```
 'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
   \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
   \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
  ],`
```

I hope I'll get a quick answer.

I tried to add some headers to my axios config like:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
       headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
     }
});
```

But not working

Comment: Yes my front end url is that, 127.0.0.1:5173. I am using VITE.
Do you mean I should remove SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in the .env file and add it here : 

**'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))), ?**

I have alse tried localhost:PORT but it still not working.

Comment: Just change your FRONTEND_URL to localhost:5173, as i said before 127.0.0.1:5173 is different of localhost:5173, make sure you acces the app with the same url

Comment: Waw. I changed every url in my .env file to localhost and PORT if needed and also made my frontend request with localhost:5173 instead of 127.0.0.1:5173 as you said and now it is working perfectly.

Thank you @Dyos

Comment: And you must also add except url like login, register on VerifyCsrfToken middleware to not verify csrf